# Enzyme fail to find with constructor selector, but succeed with display name selector

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-component, react-test-renderer

I am using **Jest** and **Enzyme** for my React app testing.

my folder structure looks like

- /src

  - /__test__

    - /LevelComponents

      - OuterComp.test.js
  - /components

    - /LevelComponents

      - OuterComp.js
    - /Widgets

      - ChenDropdown.js

`OuterComp.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import ChenDropdown from '../Widgets/ChenDropdown'

class OuterComp extends Component {

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <ChenDropdown />
          <ChenDropdown />
        </div>
      )
  }
}

export default OuterComp
```

`ChenDropdown.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class ChenDropdown extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>test</h1>
  }
}

export default ChenDropdown
```

`OuterComp.test.js`

```
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import Enzyme, { mount } from 'enzyme'

import OuterComp from '../../components/LevelComponents/OuterComp'
import ChenDropdown from '../../components/widgets/ChenDropdown'

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

describe('test', () => {
  it('test', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<OuterComp />)
    console.log(wrapper.debug())
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true)
    expect(wrapper.find('ChenDropdown').length).toBe(2)
    expect(wrapper.find(ChenDropdown).length).toBe(2)
  })
})
```

The result is the test can pass

```
expect(wrapper.find('ChenDropdown').length).toBe(2)
```

but fails at

```
expect(wrapper.find(ChenDropdown).length).toBe(2)
```

`wrapper.debug()` outputs:

```
<OuterComp>
  <div>
    <ChenDropdown>
      <h1>
        test
      </h1>
    </ChenDropdown>
    <ChenDropdown>
      <h1>
        test
      </h1>
    </ChenDropdown>
  </div>
</OuterComp>
```

I wonder why, and when I can use it directly, and when I have to put string around it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I was being dumb, I had a typo in my import, `widgets` should be `Widgets`